# Magento 2.4: Create Order Programatically with custom Order ID

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.4, importexport, place-order

**Please Note - I am able to create order programatically , just i want new created order to have specific order ID instead of auto generated order id**

Below is code to create order Programatically , please help me with where i need to change in order to use custom order id

```
  public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
        263135
        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
 
        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }
 
        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
 
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
 
        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
 
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
 
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
 
        // Create Order From Quote
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
        
        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if($order->getEntityId()){
            $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
        }else{
            $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about  order increment Id?

Comment: yes increment and order id both

Comment: @AmitBera can u help with it

Comment: Create new order id is the critical point. But You can change increment id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the process of creating quote, add the following line,

```
$quote->setReservedOrderId("YourOrderId");
```

**Please note that you need to make sure that the order id does not already exist!**

This should be done **before saving the quote** `$quote->save();`

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks it worked, can you help me with how to set order date

Comment: Good to hear that :) I haven't updated order date before, but after creating order you can try loading the order and update date, like $order->setCreatedAt("2021-06-13 10:25:23"); and save it with help of order repository

Comment: thanks one last thing can i set custom shipping charges i tried but it did not worked

Comment: Like created_at field, you can try custom shipping update on order as well

Comment: is there way to add out of stock product / disabled products also ?

Comment: Nope, you cannot do that